# browser console outputs XMLHttpRequest cannot load

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Page fails to send xmlhttprequest. Chrome console shows

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load www.XXX.
>   Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http,
>   data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function LoadFinance() {
        $(function() {
            var url = "www.XXX";
            $.getJSON( url,
               function(json){
                  console.log(json);
               });
        });
     }


    setInterval( LoadFinance, 5000 ); <!--5s-->

</script>
```

Comment: `"XMLHttpRequest cannot load".` is that ALL it says? are you laoding this page "locally" (i.e. file:/// rather than http:// ?)

Comment: p.s. `$(function() {` is the short form of `$(document).ready(function() {` - so you should see why wrapping the code in `LoadFinance` in `$(function() {` is not required

Comment: url is not local address.

Comment: check the developer tools network tab to see what is being received in the request

Comment: The server is tomcat, logfile shows:` INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-10] org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service Error parsing H    TTP request header`

Comment: well, investigate that

Comment: I've edited the source code. Is it right now?  Automatically send HTTP request every 5 seconds once the page loads and outputs received JSON data in console.

Comment: That's what it would do - if it weren't a **cross origin request** (just read the edited question ... you ARE loading the **page** using `file:///` - therefore cross origin will fail ... always ... CORS headers wont help)  ... my first comment was "are you loading the **file** locally" and you said "no" ...

Comment: Thanks. I understand. The url should be local address.Can you post an answer as for this problem? So I can accept it.

Comment: no, because chrome will fail if the **file** is `file:///` - regardless of the **url**